# Combining dates and values in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that has columns for 4 different metrics.  DepositReceived, DepositPaid, BalanceReceived and BalancePaid. For each of those, there is a column for date and one for value

- DepositRecievedDate
- DepositReceivedValue
- DepositPaidDate
- DepositPaidValue
- BalanceReceivedDate
- BalanceReceivedValue
- BalancePaidDate
- BalancePaidValue

I am looking to take the date field and create a bucket for each year/month combination, that shows the total value for received and for paid (Deposit + balance)

I am able to get the values summed per metric using QUERY and Year() and Month(), but I cant get the received and paid to join the same bucket in different columns so I can do a calc on Received-Paid.

Any ideas on how to do this in Google Sheets?

Comment: I can get it to where I join the "IN" values (DepositReceived and BalanceReceived) and have that sorted by year/month. And I can do the same for the "OUT" values, DepositPaid, BalancePaid. I just now need to join the IN and OUT on the same year/months and then do a difference calculation.  I'm wondering if I should try to do the join in a SQL query or in the sheet calculations.

Comment: If easier, I can have 4 different tabs that have colulmns - Year, Month, Value. And if I could join all four tabs into one tab using gsheet calcs instead of query, I can do that too. It would be (DepositReceived+BalanceReceived)-(DepositPaid+BalancePaid)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Here is a version of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CMPJ1HDi4HQwbOZo7qFAVPsaRhTtbbZ7CzPYk97oETA/edit?usp=sharing. The data tab has the dates and values for the deposits and balance received and paid.  The Output tab should sum the values for Received (Deposit + Balance) and Paid (Deposit + Balance) per month per year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in C2 and drag down:

```
=IFERROR({
 SUM(FILTER({Data!A$3:A; Data!E$3:E}, MONTH({Data!B$3:B; Data!F$3:F})=MONTH(B2&1), 
 YEAR({Data!B$3:B; Data!F$3:F})=IF(A2="", MAX(INDIRECT("Data!J2:J"&ROW())), A2))), 
 SUM(FILTER({Data!C$3:C; Data!G$3:G}, MONTH({Data!D$3:D; Data!H$3:H})=MONTH(B2&1), 
 YEAR({Data!D$3:D; Data!H$3:H})=IF(A2="", MAX(INDIRECT("Data!J2:J"&ROW())), A2)))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a way to have the formula also list out the year and month, just what is available in the data?

Comment: you have those listed in A:B range

Comment: I submitted this as the answer, I'm just interested in the formula populating columns A-D automatically, so there arent years and months that are blank..  I see it is populating based no the year/month, but could it also populate the year/month name using a formula I paste in cell A1 or A2?